# Problem using a for loop and start-process to call powershell script

Tags: powershell

Could someone please help me on this. I have created two powershell script one is suppose to call the other one lets call it script2.ps1

script2.ps1 - accepts two arguments computername and the type of remediation

example:

```
list=get-content c:\computer.txt

foreach ($pc in $list){
    start-process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-noexit", "-file `C:\temp\client fix\script2.ps1`", "-type install", "-computer $i"
}
```

The intention is for each computer in the list to execute script2.ps1 on separate process. The script runs fine if start-process is not being used example:

```
powershell.exe  -file 'C:\temp\client fix\Script2.ps1' -type install -computer $i
```

Comment: So what is it doing instead? Can you clarify how its not working correctly for you?

Comment: using this in the for loop powershell.exe  -file 'C:\temp\client fix\Script2.ps1' -type install -computer $i  will execute the script2.ps1 on the first computer and will not process the next computer until script2.ps1 has completed. I want the script to initiate script2.ps1 on first computer on a separate process so it does not wait for first computer to complete then it moves on to the next one.

Comment: You should consider Start-Job for this

Answer (score 0):

The `Start-Process` help explains:

> Specifies parameters or parameter values to use when this cmdlet starts the process. **If parameters or parameter values contain a space, they need surrounded with escaped double quotes.**

Your file paramater does not have an escaped double quote, but a backtick that is doing nothing.

```
start-process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-noexit", "-file `"C:\temp\client fix\script2.ps1`"", "-type install", "-computer $i"
```

Furthermore you mix arguments for `powershell.exe` (-noexit, -file) with arugments for your script (-type, -computer). Also your variable `$i` is never assigned.

Anyways, more important is to know, that there is no reason for `start-process`. Simplify your script by using the call operator `&`.

```
$list=get-content c:\computer.txt

foreach ($pc in $list){
    & "C:\temp\client fix\script2.ps1" -type install -computer $pc
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The simplified script works fine but it doesn't move on to the next pc until all the steps in script2.ps1 has completed. I thought maybe using start-process will open a new process for each computer in the list then will quickly move on to the next one as a result multiple computer can simultaneously execute the script. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: start-process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-noexit", "-file `"C:\temp\client fix\script2.ps1`"", "-type install -computer $i"

Comment: Finally manage to get it working, thankyou guys for the help. I've been trying to figure this out for weeks now.                                                                             start-process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-noexit", "-file `"C:\temp\client fix\script2.ps1`"", "-type install -computer $i"